# Gameobject.find is returning null

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am tired to debugging but don't know what is the problem

```
foreach (string go in dist)
{
    Debug.Log("gameobject texture change " + go);
    Debug.Log(go.ToString());
    Debug.Log(go.GetType());
    string s = go;
    string ss = "GRB_BLD_RESIDENT_z17x68817y86702_V0_L9_2015_18";
    Debug.Log(GameObject.Find("GRB_BLD_RESIDENT_z17x68817y86702_V0_L9_2015_18").name);
    Debug.Log(GameObject.Find(ss).name);
    if (GameObject.Find(s.ToString()) != null)
    {
        Debug.Log(GameObject.Find(s).name);
        Debug.Log("gameobject is not null");
    }
    else {
        Debug.Log("gameobject is null");
    }
```

if I use this,

```
Debug.Log(GameObject.Find("GRB_BLD_RESIDENT_z17x68817y86702_V0_L9_2015_18").name);
```

it will bring the game object but using loop it is not working. I have log all names all are right and same.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you're trying to find all gameobjects in `dist`, correct? 
What does your `Debug.Log(go.ToString())` output?

go is already a string, I suspect getting a `ToString()` from a `string` will simply return `string` instead of the value of the string.

Answer (score 0):

the reason following code is working is  Debug.Log(GameObject.Find("GRB_BLD_RESIDENT_z17x68817y86702_V0_L9_2015_18").name); beacause you are using Gameobject class and accessing its name property.

But in your foreach loop you are iterating over a dict and using its string element if you use foreach(Gameobject obj in dict) then the above will work .

You can also do this if(go == "nameOfObject")

Hope it helps